# Accessing phone setting with lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hello I am developing software that can access phone settings and enable hotspot settings. I was wondering if there is a way for me to access those settings with lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, not with Corona SDK. It might be possible with Corona Enterprise.

Comment: If I cant do it through lua should I write the code in the language specific to the mobile platform.

Comment: With Corona SDK you can only use Lua and you can't access what you need. With Corona Enterprise you write in a combination of Lua/Objective C/C++ for iOS and Lua/Java/C++ for Android.